# Trying to Send Emails to People if Checkbox is Checked

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm using Access, a Form, and an Subform, and I'm trying to loop through checkboxes and if they are checked, send an email to the person that's checked off.

The problem is that I have a method or data member not found.
This line throws an error.
Me.qry_Ryan_Emails.Work_Email

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub Command1_Click()

For Each ctrl In Me.qry_Ryan_Emails.Controls

    If TypeName(ctrl) = "CheckBox" Then
        If ctrl.Enabled = True Then
            'Debug.Print TypeName(ctrl)

            Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
                Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
                eSubject = Me.Subject.Text
                eBody = Me.Message.Text

                On Error Resume Next

                With OutMail
                    .To = Me.qry_Ryan_Emails.Work_Email
                    .CC = ""
                    .BCC = ""
                    .Subject = eSubject
                    .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
                    .Display
                    .HTMLBody = eBody & vbCrLf & .HTMLBody
                    '.Send
                End With

                On Error GoTo 0
                Set OutMail = Nothing
                Set OutApp = Nothing


        End If

    End If
Next ctrl

End Sub
```

Finally, is it better to concatenate all email recipients into one email and just send out one email, rather than multiple emails?  That may be a better way of doing it.  Any thoughts, anyone?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub Command1_Click()

AllEmails = ""
For Each ctrl In Me.qry_Ryan_Emails.Controls

    If TypeName(ctrl) = "CheckBox" Then
        If ctrl.Enabled = True Then
            AllEmails = AllEmails & " " & Me!qry_Ryan_Emails.Form.Work_Email
        End If
    End If

Next ctrl

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    eSubject = Me!Subject
    eBody = Me!Message

    On Error Resume Next

    With OutMail
        .To = AllEmails
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = eSubject
        .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
        .Display
        .HTMLBody = eBody & vbCrLf & .HTMLBody
        .Send
    End With

    On Error GoTo 0
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

This line concatenates all emails into one string.

```
AllEmails = AllEmails & " " & Me!qry_Ryan_Emails.Form.Work_Email
```

Then I just send 1 email to the group.

This link is very useful for referencing controls on forms and subforms.

http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can do essentially the same thing using a ListBox and selecting multiple items in the ListBox.

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub Command1_Click()
Dim varItem As Variant
Dim lngRow As Long
Dim strMsg As String

AllEmails = ""

With Me.List_Emails
    For lngRow = 0 To .ListCount - 1
        If .Selected(lngRow) Then
            AllEmails = AllEmails & .Column(2, lngRow)
        End If
    Next lngRow
End With


Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    eSubject = Me!Subject
    eBody = Me!Message

    On Error Resume Next

    With OutMail
        .To = AllEmails
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = eSubject
        .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
        .Display
        .HTMLBody = eBody & vbCrLf & .HTMLBody
        '.Send
    End With

    On Error GoTo 0
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```